# Choose a default colors between multiple shades in Chakra UI theme

Tags: reactjs, themes, chakra-ui

I'm gonna use a `primary` color with different shades in my Chakra theme. But one of the shades is going to be used more often and I would like to use it as `default`.

```
export const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    primary: {
      _default: '#a8d6d3', // THIS IS THE primary.400
      50: '#eef7f6',
      100: '#dcefed',
      200: '#cbe7e5',
      300: '#badedc',
      400: '#a8d6d3',
      500: '#86c6c2',
      600: '#63b6b0',
      700: '#499c97',
      800: '#397975',
      900: '#295754',
    },
  },
});
```

Instead of using `primary.400` over and over, I would like to just use `primary`.

The `_default` keyword does not seem to work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: hey did you figure it out in the end? I'm looking for this exact thing but can't find it

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/foundations/colors.ts) you can find default colors available in Chakra default theme.

You can add your own colors like you did for the primary, also whenever you are adding your custom colors you should create different shades from `50` to `900` ([this](https://smart-swatch.netlify.app) is the recommended app you can use for generating different shades).

Chakra by default uses `teal` color as `primary` color, so if you want one of your custom colors (primary, secondary...or whatever name you choose for your generated shades) to be the default one you should use this method `withDefaultColorScheme({ colorScheme: 'primary or secondary...' })`, in your custom theme object.

```
// in your example
    export const theme = extendTheme({
      colors: {
        primary: {
          _default: '#a8d6d3', // THIS IS THE primary.400
          50: '#eef7f6',
          100: '#dcefed',
          200: '#cbe7e5',
          300: '#badedc',
          400: '#a8d6d3',
          500: '#86c6c2',
          600: '#63b6b0',
          700: '#499c97',
          800: '#397975',
          900: '#295754',
        },
      },
    }, withDefaultColorScheme({ colorScheme: 'primary' }));
```

To answer you question: e.g. for `<Button colorScheme="primary" variant="solid"></Button>` component, Chakra by default in light mode takes white color for button text and `shade 500` for background color and `shade 600` for background color when you hover the button. That's because of [accessible contrast ratio](https://webaim.org/articles/contrast/) between background and foreground color.

Also if you use component `<Text color="primary">Some text</Text>` Chakra will use primary `shade 500` for the text color.

To set default shade for primary text color you should use [semanticTokens](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/semantic-tokens) in your custom theme object. Chakra uses these [options](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/semantic-tokens.ts) as default.

```
const semanticTokens = {
  colors: {
    'chakra-body-text': { _light: 'primary.main', _dark: 'primary.50' },
    'chakra-body-bg': { _light: '#F3F2F9', _dark: 'gray.800' },
    primary: {
      _light: 'primary.main',
      _dark: 'primary.50',
    },
    secondary: {
      default: 'secondary.main',
      _dark: 'secondary.50',
    },
  },
};
```

[Here](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/components/button.ts) you can find options for buttons.